# Internet connection problems

Tags: router, internet, internet-connection

This  morning my internet was extremely slow and I restarted my router. My computer registered internet connection and I could now use my wireless printer and scanner without problem. However, when I wanted to go to google.com my browser showed my the homepage of my router instead of the actual webpage. Windows N. Connectivity says I have to log in. I did that but nothing happens. How can I fix this? 
Sorry if this is the wrong forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to the message displayed by the computer it sounds like the router is not connected to the world wide web. Your wireless printer and scanner both work on a local intranet with your router as an intermediary between your PC and device. They don't need internet to function. All though your router is on and broadcasting a wireless signal it does not have an internet connection. I would provide a soft reset on the router/modem by unplugging it for 60 seconds. Also ensure to restart the computer itself. If it doesn't solve the issue there could be a service provider disruption or the device may have failed.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is subscription problem and you need to call you internet services provider. they will tell you the exact issue and solution.